# Sound and ALSA stop working a few reboots after ALSA reinstall

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, soundcard

On a computer under Ubuntu 16.04, the sound had stopped working, seemingly without reason. I followed the troubleshooting steps and reinstalled ALSA and pulse-audio, deleted some old files apparently related to OSS, and got the sound to work again.

I rebooted the computer a few times and the sound kept working (tested on Youtube through Firefox and Rythmox). Now suddenly after another reboot and nothing special done, the sound disappeared again.

The graphic "Sound" tab only shows a dummy output, alsamixer gives me a "*Can't open, no such file or directory*" error, and the script from http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh gives me this output :

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=6b23c44d3e0fa32af3aea00707ca46177c59cd6c

Additional info given by the command sequence in the [step 4 of the troubleshooting page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) :

https://pastebin.com/Uei0rYHe

What can I possibly do from that point ?

Comment: List this output: `pacmd list-sinks | grep 'index*\|alsa*\|driver*\|device*\|*module*'`

Comment: * index: 0
 driver: <module-null-sink.c>
  device.description = "Sortie fictive"
  device.class = "abstract"
  device.icon_name = "audio-card"

Comment: You should see a lot more than that with several lines of alsa devices and driver descriptions. Clearly, alsa isn't installed. If alsamixer won't open that's another pointer. When you say you re-installed alsa, what did you do?

Comment: I simply used apt remove / apt install. Remember everything was working fine, alsamixer etc as well, until after a simple reboot without any additional install it wasn't. I want to emphasize that I rebooted multiple times before without doing anything else than testing the sound, and it kept working.

Comment: @PaulBenson I added a pastebin link in the main post that gives some extra information.

Comment: I've seen it, but the results of the command I gave you indicate there is no alsa, or it's corrupted. Whatever, it's not loading. Just looking at your hardware, what's the output for `sudo lshw -C multimedia`?

Comment: So after further testing, I think it might have been a hardware issue : I plugged a "jack into USB" adaptor and the it worked instantly. Considering this, and the fact that the sound-card stopped working for no apparent reason, I guess hardware issue is the most likely cause, even though I've never heard of such an example.